# ETag caching on aws

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, caching, aws-lambda

I need to migrate an API Server powered by node **restify** to something using API Gateway + lambda functions provided by AWS.

The API Server (GET/POST simple stuff no DB involved) is served as a proxy server to talk to a CMS system to fetch data for clients.

At the moment, the **etag** caching is done through **restify** middleware. I wonder what I need to do to achieve the same thing in new solution (API Gateway + lambda)?

A side note, what I come up with is - save the response from CMS into S3/CloudFront with **ETag** caching mechanism enabled and let them determine if cached response on the browser can be used.

I wonder if that is a good practice?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

First of all API gateway has a seperate [caching option](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-caching.html) where you can cache the responses for a particular TTL more suitable for API content caching.

If your CMS responses mainly contain static content and the requirement for proxy is to passthrough and cache the content, use AWS CloudFront directly infront of your CMS.

If you are only using API gateway Lambda as a proxy and also significant data transformation or generation done in Lambda, then you can setup AWS CloudFront infront of API Gateway to cache the responses.

If only very light data transformation and generation happens at the proxy (API Gateway with Lambda), the you can only use CloudFront infront of your CMS and use Edge Lambda runs at CloudFront edge locations to do the light modifications for the responses coming from the CMS also with caching.

I don't see a clear need in storing the responses in S3 and then serve through CloudFront unless your CMS has direct support in pushing content to S3 automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. What do you mean by use CloudFront in front of my CMS? 

CMS we are using is a third-party one and we do some basic transformations on original data and forward the results to the client.

Comment: You can put CloudFront as a proxy and a cache, to cache content from CMS

Comment: is that possible if I do not have the control over the cms? I'm using a third party cms called contentful

Comment: And I call their api to fetch the contents

Comment: Has anyone heard of ETag caching? Seems not.